# Which forum module is being used here

Tags: drupal

Can anybody tell me whether it is using Drupal Forum or AF module in this forum:
http://forum.acronis.com

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Advanced Forum with a custom Advanced Forum theme.

View the page's source and see references to files like `/sites/all/modules/Forum/advanced_forum/styles/acroboxy/images/topic-sticky.png` which indicates advanced_forum is being used, and in this case with a theme acroboxy which is likely custom made by Acronis.

Also, read [Advanced Forum's features](http://drupal.org/node/841056) and see that many of them are in use on the site you linked.